# Dplyr - choosing value in column based on lowest value in other column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working on a dataset with multiple biopsies per patient ID. I need to find the biopsy result closest to a specific date (individual per patient). A dummy dataset can be seen below

```
df <- data.frame(m1 = c("1","1","1","2","2","2"), 
                 patodate=c("2013-06-03","2014-01-06","2018-11-23","2004-03-03","2018-06-25","2018-12-19"), 
                 baselinedate=c("2018-11-09","2018-11-09","2018-11-09","2018-07-24","2018-07-24","2018-07-24"),
                 biopsy=c("1","2","3","1","2","3"))
```

I have then calculated the time difference between patodate and baselinedate

```
df$patodate <- as.Date(df$patodate)
df$baselinedate <- as.Date(df$baselinedate)

df <- df%>%
  group_by(m1) %>%
  mutate(diff = baselinedate-recdate)
```

My question is now - I want to add a new column called 'status' which shows (by group m1) the 'biopsy' result with the time difference closest to 0.
The end result would be

```
df <- data.frame(m1 = c("1","1","1","2","2","2"), 
                 patodate=c("2013-06-03","2014-01-06","2018-11-23","2004-03-03","2018-06-25","2018-12-19"), 
                 baselinedate=c("2018-11-09","2018-11-09","2018-11-09","2018-07-24","2018-07-24","2018-07-24"),
                 biopsy=c("1","2","3","1","2","3"),
                 status=c("3","3","3","2","2","2"))
```

I hope someone understands the issue and is able to help. Many thanks

Kind regards,

Tobias Berg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(m1) %>%
     mutate(status =  abs(patodate - baselinedate),
          status = which(status == min(status))[1]) %>% 
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  m1    patodate   baselinedate biopsy status
  <chr> <date>     <date>       <chr>   <int>
1 1     2013-06-03 2018-11-09   1           3
2 1     2014-01-06 2018-11-09   2           3
3 1     2018-11-23 2018-11-09   3           3
4 2     2004-03-03 2018-07-24   1           2
5 2     2018-06-25 2018-07-24   2           2
6 2     2018-12-19 2018-07-24   3           2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  group_by(m1) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), ymd),
         helper = abs(difftime(baselinedate,patodate))) %>% 
  mutate(status = biopsy[helper==min(helper)]) %>% 
  select(-helper)
```

```
  m1    patodate   baselinedate biopsy status
  <chr> <date>     <date>       <chr>  <chr> 
1 1     2013-06-03 2018-11-09   1      3     
2 1     2014-01-06 2018-11-09   2      3     
3 1     2018-11-23 2018-11-09   3      3     
4 2     2004-03-03 2018-07-24   1      2     
5 2     2018-06-25 2018-07-24   2      2     
6 2     2018-12-19 2018-07-24   3      2
```

Comment: Hi TarJae. I'm going with your solution. 
Unfortunately, I didn't take into account that in the real dataset, I would have different biopsies with the same timediff (i.e 11 days before and after baselinedate or two biopsies taken on the same date but with different results). How would you handle this?

Comment: Could you please provide an updated dataframe with the new situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can get index of minimum absolute value of difference between the dates for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(m1) %>%
  mutate(status = which.min(abs(patodate - baselinedate))) %>%
  ungroup

#  m1    patodate   baselinedate biopsy status
#  <chr> <date>     <date>       <chr>   <int>
#1 1     2013-06-03 2018-11-09   1           3
#2 1     2014-01-06 2018-11-09   2           3
#3 1     2018-11-23 2018-11-09   3           3
#4 2     2004-03-03 2018-07-24   1           2
#5 2     2018-06-25 2018-07-24   2           2
#6 2     2018-12-19 2018-07-24   3           2
```